# mostrar campo en select de base de datos - php

Tags: php

buen dia, tengo un select y necesito mostrar de mi base de datos el resultado de mi campo suspender, he intentado hacerlo pero no he podido cargar ese campo.

```
$documento="123456",
$fetch_user_by_email = "SELECT suspender  FROM `users` WHERE `documento`=:documento";
$query_stmt = $conn->prepare($fetch_user_by_email);
$query_stmt->bindValue(':documento', $documento,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_stmt->execute();
//se agrego
$resultado = $query_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
//necesito cargar el resultado de mi campo suspender de mi base de datos aqui
$micampo = $resultado->suspender;
```

Comment: Creo que te refieres a algo asi como: `$micampo = $query_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)->suspender`... si es así léete la documentación de [fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch) para más información

Comment: pero no me funciona asi no mas, me podrías colaborar con mi código?

Comment: pq pasas como parametro suspender?

Comment: ¿no te muestra el resultado esperado si haces un `echo $micampo;` despues?  Si no es así quizas debas dividirlo en dos, es decir, primero algo asi: `$resultado = $query_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);` y en la siguiente línea esto: `$micampo = $resultado->suspender;`

Comment: @gbianchi no lo interpretaba yo como parámetro, sino como una clave del objeto obtenido en el fetch anterior, pero no puedo probarlo, así que quizás me he equivocado.  Por eso mi siguiente comentario ha sido de hacerlo en dos pasos.

Comment: mira.. hay varias cosas ahi.. dice suspener (en lugar de suspender), le faltan las comillas.. y no es un parametro de esa query...

Comment: ah, te refieres a ese... pensaba que hablabas de mis comentarios, jejeje... si, eso ya lo ví, pero como el OP no ha dicho si le da error he supuesto que no y lo he dejado pasar como si no estuviera para hacer mis comentarios, je.

Comment: @Giovanny ahora lo has puesto mejor, pero la linea del fetch va despues de la del execute, porque primero hay que ejecutar la consulta (execute) antes de sacar sus resultados (fetch).

Comment: agregue el código como me lo indicaron pero no me funciona, que estoy haciendo mal ?

Comment: ¿que sucede cuando haces un `echo $micampo;` después de todo eso?  no te muestra nada?  ¿te aparece algun error en alguna parte antes?

Comment: no muestra nada al llamar a echo $micampo;

Comment: ¿y si haces la consulta a pelo en tu phpmyadmin te devuelve algo?  A ver si estás consultando algo que no tiene nada en esa columna.  Lo raro es que no veas algun error por alguna parte si realmente algo está mal, por eso pienso que más bien la consulta no devuelve nada o null.

Comment: si me aparece un error "Trying to get property 'suspender' of non-object" y el error se resalta sobre  esta linea"$micampo = $resultado->suspender;"

Comment: Comprueba la consulta que estás construyendo directamente en el mysql, ya sea con phpmyadmin o con lo que dispongas para hacerlo, pues diria que no está devolviendo nada de nada y por eso luego no construye el objeto correctamente.  Por lo que parece diría que te está devolviendo un `false` (valor booleano) que indica que la consulta no arroja resultados válidos o es incorrecta de por sí.

Comment: O sea, según tu código, la consulta sería así en SQL puro: `SELECT suspender  FROM users WHERE documento="123456";`, y eso es lo que debes probar en tu servidor mysql directamente a ver que error te da allí o que te devuelve realmente.  (quizás el número de documento 123456 no existe o te has equivocado de tabla u otra cosa)

Comment: listo, si era eso no estaba cargando ningún dato, muchas gracias

Comment: ok, bueno misterio resuelto pues.. saludos! :-)

Comment: Aquí has cometido un error que yo llamo *programación optimista o ingenua*. Es decir, asumiste que `$resultado` tendría siempre datos, cuando eso **podría** no ser así al menos por tres motivos: 1. No hay conexión; 2. La consulta fue errónea; 3. La consulta no arroja datos porque la condición no se cumple. En un código tan sencillo hay tres posibles casos de error (lógico) y no afrontas ninguno de los tres. Has sido demasiado *optimista* pensando que la vida es bella y que siempre las cosas van como uno espera... ERROR! Debes prever lo que puede salir mal, para resolverlo desde el código.